# Xamarin: Error when loading layout axml file in android

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

When I create a axml file and try to open it in designer view for android layout I get the followign error message:

```
"Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of Java"
```

and with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main"
```

What I have tried to do so far is reinstalling the Java JDK, upgrading it from 1.7 to 1.8 as well as downgrading, always with 64-bit version. Tried to introduce the environmental variable _JAVA_OPTIONS and change it do have the value -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, but did not help.

There were other solutions but they were applicable only for xamarin studio on iOS and as I am using xamarin integration on windows with Visual Studio 2015, they did not apply for.

So my question is, are there any solution to this problem?

P.S Please say if I did not provide enough information or was no clear.

Thank you.

**UPDATE 30/05/2019**
Probably a little too late, however I have managed to figure out this problem back in the days by matching the Java and Android sdk versions. It seemed one version of java was not very happy with particular android sdk version and vice verse, so just try to install a different one until they match up.

Answer (score 0):

Well hi,

I had this problem quite for a while and managed to fix it following the instructions on xamarin forums. So what i did was

1. Uninstalled all java and java sdk prior 1.8 and kept only 1.8
2. Added an enviromental variable for MaxPermSize to 250m
3. Restarted windows
4. Changed the registry values as shown below

[image]

But i will have to admit that this worked only for some days. Then i received the same error again and got another solution

I kept using VS2015 but the User Interface i designed in Android studio copying the code from Android Studio to VS2015. I know this is not a solution but i refuce to spent more time on xamarin errors that come up all the time.

UPDATE: I have posted an answer that solved my problem on
[Xamarin VS2015 designer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018114/xamarin-vs2015-designer-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

hello I also meet this problem. 
I google it and find a solution for it

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78971/visual-studio-2015-xamarin-studio-2-2-connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed

1. remove mono android sdk
2. install android sdk
3. change sdk Location(Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location)

Old location:
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK

New location:
C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk