# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again, Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin Android and am facing the below error when I try to open the Main.axml file in designer mode of a blank Android project in Visual Studio 2015. Any suggestion in resolving would be greatly appreciated!

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main"
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018114/xamarin-vs2015-designer-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin VS2015 designer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018114/xamarin-vs2015-designer-not-working)